# Call and Eval function inside R

Tags: r, call, eval

I am writing a function where I want to supply a variable which contains a condition to be evaluated inside the function. For example, I have a hourval variable containing values like 0, 3, 6, 9, 18, 3, 6, 9, 18 0, 3, 18 ... I want to select the indices where hourval variable matches to 0, 6. This 0, 6  could change depending upon some other parameters. Basically they are not fixed always. So I pass a variable `g1 =  call("which", (hourval==0 | hourval == 6))`. I want this statement to be evaluated in the program. Hence I use the statement `x1 = eval(g1)`. Obviously, when I pass the variable `g1`, that time hourval variable is not generated, but it is generated just before the `eval(g1)` statement. I get error,  object `hourval` not found. Is there any other way to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Narayani Barve

Comment: I think we would get better insight into what you're doing if we would see how you get those parameters. A small working example would go a long way. Here's a little post that can be of some aid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Maybe see the code for `subset.data.frame`; that might help get you started.  On the other hand, you may want to think about another way to solve the problem; solutions in the manner you outline are often more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: please don't cross-post, especially not to an unrelated mailing list: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2011-July/012211.html

Comment: Sort of my fault. I invited Narayani to post his question here (because it's more programming in nature than geostatistical). I should have made it explicit to at least mention a crossposting.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you want?

```
> hourval <- c(0, 3, 6, 9, 18, 3, 6, 9, 18, 0, 3, 18)
> test <- c(0,6)
> which(hourval %in% test)
[1]  1  3  7 10
```

It took me a while to find it with this search strategy

```
library(fortunes)
fortune("parse")
```

but eventually got the one I remembered:

```
> fortune("parse")

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

Part of my difficulty was in the fact that I remembered the quote as having "eval(parse(".

Comment: I see you already posted it in the past. Lumley should be given about 1000 bonus points on SO.

Comment: Thank you Thomas..The first option works for me. I can send the "test" sequence as a parameter and then use which(hourval %in% test) statement in the place of eval(g1). Thank you very much

Comment: I quote that particular fortune fairly regularly at my workplace, due to a coworker who has a fondness for eval/parse.  It's an oldie but a goodie.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you seem to describe

```
f1 <- function(y) {
  hourval <- c(0, 3, 6, 9, 18, 3, 6, 9, 18, 0, 3, 18)
  eval(substitute(y))
}
f1( which(hourval %in% c(0,6)) )
```

But this is what I'd do instead.

```
f2 <- function(y) {
  hourval <- c(0, 3, 6, 9, 18, 3, 6, 9, 18, 0, 3, 18)
  which(hourval %in% y)
}
f2( c(0,6) )
```

But again, there's not enough information yet to know if either of these answer the question.